# What is the meaning of this residuals vs fitted plot? (multiple linear regression)

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, residuals

[image: Residuals vs Fitted Plot]

I am running a multiple linear regression model in RStudio at the moment and wanted to check my assumptions. As seen by the plot, my red line does not appear to be flat and instead curved in places.

I am having a difficulty interpreting this. How to interpret this curve? Is the relationship linear?

Comment: There seems to be a hole in the fitted values between roughly 80 and 110 where your model makes no prediction, and the few points which you have around this range then pull the loess line up or down. You really don't have that many points, but overall the residuals look OK to me.

Answer (score -1):

This plot is used to detect non-linearity, unequal error variances, and outliers.
Let say if the distance of errors on either side of zero line is variable then it is a case of unequal error variances. This is also mean some amount of explainable portion is in the error part. This can be improved by adding variables(predictors) which has relation with output variables
please check the link below
source : [https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat462/node/117/#:~:text=When%20conducting%20a%20residual%20analysis,unequal%20error%20variances%2C%20and%20outliers](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat462/node/117/#:%7E:text=When%20conducting%20a%20residual%20analysis,unequal%20error%20variances%2C%20and%20outliers).